# LiveView using gphoto2 and D3300

Tags: shell, camera, streaming

I try to use liveview as webcam from Nikon D3300.

LiveView for D3300 [is supported (see link)](http://www.gphoto.org/proj/libgphoto2/support.php) althou when I try to capture movie this error happens:

```
grim@xxxx:~/$ LANG=C  gphoto2  --capture-movie
Capturing preview frames as movie to 'movie.mjpg'. Press Ctrl-C to abort.      

*** Error ***              
Liveview cannot start: code 0x80000000
ERROR: Movie capture error... Exiting.
Movie capture finished (0 frames)
grim@xxxx:~/$
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have just had the exact same error code with a Nikon DSC D5200. I made an [issue on github](https://github.com/gphoto/gphoto2/issues/359) and got a respond from the one of the developers, which solved my problem.

In my case `code 0x80000000` meant according to the SDK that "The Exposure Program Mode property (...) is set to anything other than P/S/A/M.".
My camera was set to auto, so when i changed the exposure program to one of the above mentioned programs the video capture started working.

Comment: Oh, where to change that? I see auto on a wheal ontop of the camera. But it is not screwd to auto.

Comment: You should also see the letters P, S, A and M on the wheel, just turn the wheel to one of those options.